# Oracle join tables with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I ve post a pic of what im trying to accomplish ive been trying all the codes i can find online but nothing seems to work. 
[image: example]

here a snippet of the code i'm trying to use.. Am i even on the right track? PS. its an oracle DB

```html
SELECT
    q1.x, q1.y, q2.z, ...
FROM
    (SELECT ... FROM ...) q1
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ... FROM ...) q2
        ON q1.column = q2.column
```

thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join Table 2 twice, once on Table1.NUM1 and once on Table1.NUM2:

```
SELECT
    t1.A, t1.NUM1, t1.NUM2, t2a.TEXT AS TEXT1, t2b.TEXT AS TEXT2
FROM
    Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2a
        ON t1.NUM1 = t2a.NUM
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2b
        ON t1.NUM2 = t2b.NUM
```

You can also use LEFT JOINS, if rows from Table 2 are missing and you still want to include the rows of Table 1 in such cases.

In order to be able to identify the 2 instances of Table 2 you need to give them different aliases. The alias on Table 1 is just for convenience.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something profound, this is just two joins:

```
select t1.*, t2a.text as text1, t2a.text as text2
from t1 join
     t2 t2a
     on t2a.num = t1.num1 join
     t2 t2b
     on t2b.num = t1.num2;
```